# Constructors and destructors not getting called for Global Objects

Tags: c++, visual-c++, constructor, global-variables, destructor

There are two .cpp files namely

1. frontend.cpp(contains definition for `FrontEnd` class and some other additional functions) and
2. backend.cpp(contains definition for `Backend` class)

I want to use the methods of `BackEnd` class in most of the functions defined in the FrontEnd.cpp, so I have created a **global object** for the `BackEnd` class there. If I try to access the methods defined in `BackEnd` class from there, everything is working fine.

But the **constructor** and **destructor** for the `BackEnd` class is not getting called!? Will this cause any major issues in the future?

**FrontEnd.cpp** will look like this

```
BackEnd _backend; //global object

FrontEnd::initialize(){
_backend.createDB()   //works fine
}

FrontEnd::func2(){
_backend.deleteDB()   //works fine
}

otherfunc(){   //not a method of FrontEnd class but will be defined here
_backend.modifyDB()   //works fine
}
```

P.S. I am not doing anything inside the constructor and destructor functions of the `BackEnd` class except printing the log for checking whether it is getting called or not.

What kind of issues will arise in the future if they are not getting called? Should I be concerned?

I am new here, so please correct me if am wrong. Thanks :)

Comment: They probably are getting called, you are just not seeing it because the terminal is not setup yet. Probably due to this: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/siof

Comment: Is there also a global `FrontEnd` object (anywhere) and if so, does it's constructor call `initialize`?

Comment: Okay, but the log message inside the constructor call should be getting printed, right?

Comment: @BhuvanBharath Only if `<iostream>` is included in `frontend.cpp` before the global variable's definition or you create an object of type `std::ios_base::Init` before the output operation in `BackEnd`'s constructor.

Comment: If something strange happens  then you may be victim of Static Initialization Order Fiasco. It is tricky to repair without redesining the structure of your data

Comment: @user17732522 yes, there is  `FrontEnd` object but it is not global. It is local and I am calling the initialize method from that.

Comment: @BhuvanBharath So it is local in the sense that it's scope begins only when `main` has started? It is not constructed in another global variable's constructor or anything? If none of this is the case, then your only issue is the missing `#include<iostream>`. The constructor does run, but the streams haven't been setup yet when you try to do output.

Comment: Most of the comments above assume that this is a console app. Is it?
I can assure you the constructor of the BackEnd class is called. @Bhuvan Bharath is current. 
can you post a code handling "log message inside the constructor"?